# Using RDD.checkpoint to recover rdd in case of application crash

Tags: apache-spark

I am writing a Spark ( not Streaming ) application that has a many iterations. I would like to checkpoint my rdd on every Nth iteration so that if my application crashes I can rerun it from the last checkpoint. All the references I found for this use case seem to be for Spark Streaming apps where a full checkpoint of the entire program can be easily saved by an one application run and then read ( getOrCreate ) by another.

How can I read a checkpointed rdd in regular Spark?

Comment: If you ask about supported and documented way of doing this then then the answer is negative. RDD checkpoint is a different tool which specifically address lineage issues not failure recovery.

Comment: @zero323  I am confused on your comment as I am under the impression that Recovering RDD From Checkpoint Files by esteemed JL contributor alludes to whta the posting by Harel G is saying. See https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-checkpointing.html#sparkcontext-checkpointFile. The example he provided works within same APP, but not over APPS - I see fixme.